# What does "paths must precede expression" mean when using find?

Tags: find

I want show all the files that have a .bak extension.

```
kaykav@ubu2:~/Documents$ ls
cdIndex1-60  met.bak  tem.bak
```

I type the cmd :  `$ find . -name *.bak`

I'm in the correct Directory for this. I get the following message:

> find: paths must precede expression: tem.bak

What does that mean? Man pages are no help.

Comment: Related post - [“find: paths must precede expression:” How do I specify a recursive search that also finds files in the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495501/465053)

Answer (score 27):

Try putting it in quotes:

`find . -name '*.bak'`

When you simply use `find . -name *.bak` in that directory shell expands it to `find . -name tem.bak met.bak` (i.e. interprets `*` as the wildcard)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm not sure I comprehend the answer but it works. I thought *.bak means  'all' results that have a .bak ending.

Comment: @kaykav When you run `find . -name *.bak`, the third command-line argument, `*.bak`, is *expanded* by the shell before it is passed to `find`. Shell expansion will convert it to a space-delimited list of all the filenames in the current directory that match it, i.e., all the files whose names consist of zero or more characters (`*`) followed by `.bak`. When you enclose `*.bak` in quotes, that *escapes* the `*` wildcard, so the expression is passed unexpanded. You could alternatively use `find . -name \*.bak`.